# Adding post tags without capability edit_posts

Tags: tags, capabilities, user-roles

I have a custom role called Event Contributor whose capabilities are limited to the post type "events". The role does *not* have the capability "edit_posts".

The post type "events" has custom categories, but uses the regular post tags.

The problem is that users with the role Event Contributor are not allowed to add tags to an event, because they don't have the capability "edit_posts".

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Could you elaborate on how your custom role is set up? `edit_post` is the most basic capability to have to be able to do anything, native Contributor role (which is first above Subscriber) has it.

Comment: The role behaves like Contributor, but then only for a custom post. I want the user to be able to use the regular post tags, but not to edit regular posts.